# Is there any way to catch Ho-Oh and Lugia In Pokémon Leafgreen?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I saw people catching Ho-Oh and Lugia from a island using a mystery ticket , is that true? Because I don't get any mystery ticket even I type that words in shops note. He just say that Oh you know about Mystery Gift or something like that. Can I catch Ho-Oh and Lugia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lugia and Ho-Oh can indeed be caught in Emerald, FireRed, and LeafGreen, but... **it's not simple**.

Lugia and Ho-Oh are located on an island called **Navel Rock**. To go there, you need an item called the **MysticTicket** - a ticket for a ferry. This item is, however, not available in the game...

What you have done is enabled Mystery Gift. Mystery Gift is a feature that lets you receive new things for the game via link cable from events - that is, real-world events held by Nintendo. However, events were timed and only available at certain locations, which was long ago now. The MysticTicket was distributed through some of these events. However, there still is *one* way to get it today...

If you have a friend who has gotten the MysticTicket before, you can **get the mystery gift from them via link cable**. This is a long shot, of course - it's not simple to find someone who has it these days - but it's possible.

Of course, you can also cheat - but that'd be too easy, wouldn't it? ;)